# Can a forum affect on web space?

Tags: web

I want to create a web site and its web space is not unlimited and I want to add forum to my web site but I don't know that with choosing a title for discussion and with posting text from people in that forum the web space will decreased ???!!
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSpace generally refers to the space in which you put your code + HTML + images ...all resources..
And forum's size is not dependent on that.
whenever you post a thread it doesn't create a separate page for it, instead it stored the data in DB so the DB space is important in your case.

Comment: and I think db will affect on web space ? yes? so more text in forum will make the DB be increased and if db be increased , the web space will be decreased ! yes? is it right?

Comment: WebSpace Term generally doesn't cover DB size. DB is given separately by web host

Comment: You can ask your web host. [if its the case]